# Infinite scroll fires too often although flag is used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So, I tried my hands on infinite scrolling with jQuery. Problem is, as soon as I scroll down a few pixels, the function fires something like 50 times which has a very high impact on my server due to a LOT of huge gifs on the page. I was advised to use a flag but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

```
<script>
    $(window).data('ajaxready', true).scroll(function(e) {
        if ($(window).data('ajaxready') == false) return;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 0) {
            $(window).data('ajaxready', false);
            var box = $("#maincontent");
                //Just append some content here
                $.get("more.php", function(data){
                box.html(box.html() + data);
                });
            $(window).data('ajaxready', true);
        }   
    });
</script>
```

The actual body looks just like this:

```
<body>
<div id="maincontent">
<?php
    include ('more.php');
    echo "ENDE<br>";
?>
</div>
</body>
```

The more.php generates enough content to exactly fill a little bit more than a fullscreen on a standart FULL HD display.

edit: as far as I understand it, this code should do the following: ONLY load more content, when the bottom border of the viewport hits the bottom border of the document. This is the desired result but not what is actually happening. What IS happening is: content gets appended EVERY time the user scrolls ONE pixel.

Comment: try moving `$(window).data('ajaxready', true);` inside the `$.get` callback

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, it outputs the respective values, which are fine. Nevertheless, my GET gets fired for EVERY pixel the user scrolls (just learned it doesn't matter in which direction the user scrolls).

Comment: did you try moving the code as suggested?

Comment: Even without the flag, the code you have should _not_ produce the behavior you're describing. I'm curious what output you would get if you were to log `$(window).scrollTop()`, `$(document).height()`, and $(window).height()` within the scroll event handler.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I did move the code as you suggested. The result remains unchanged: content gets appended for every pixel the user scrolls. The flag doesn't seem to work because the php to be appended only takes like 20ms to load... Why is the "load only when bottom of page is reached"-logic not working?...